# Rosh Hashonoh. Pray for forgiveness and needs – or not?

Tags: tefilla, rosh-hashanah-new-year, forgiving-mechilah

In my copy of the Siddur HaGr”a there is an introduction to the prayers of Rosh Hashonoh. It is quite clear there that we mention neither our sins nor our needs.

> [image: intro prayers r.h.]
>
> Therefore our Rabbis forbade us to mention any type of sin in order
> that a person should not request forgiveness for his soul because he
> has gone off the way. Similarly a person should not turn to the woes
> of his heart and request children, life and sustenance like a dog
> barking because in this way he will awaken judgement ...

How is it  then that after reciting the 13 middos when taking out the Torah, the following prayer is printed which explicitly asks for forgiveness from sins (and later asks for our needs)?

> [image: ribon prayer]
>
> Lord of the world, fulfil our request for good and supply our requests
> and forgive us and our households the various types of sin,with all
> sorts of  forgiveness and remember us for good before You …

Is the prayer when taking out the Torah somehow different, is this a mistake of the printers or is there another reason?

Comment: I would venture to say that the "intro" is referring to the Amida (and its repetition).  After all, it's codified in Shulchan Aruch that we wish each other a Shana Tova after Maariv, and we "do simanim" with the Yehi Ratzons for "mundane" requests. Then we go do Tashlich

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have Imgur blocked on my computer, but if this is the prayer said with the 13 attributes, then the answer is that the Vilna Gaon held to not say it. Look in the brackets [here](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=57996&st=&pgnum=270). The printers were not following the opinion of the Vilna Gaon.

Comment: Is it that he said not to say it or that he didn't say it because it wasn't printed in standard ashkenazi siddurim until later? We're not talking about a very old custom.

Comment: Ma’aseh Rav brings that his custom was not to say any Ribono shel Olam prayer on chag. (@doubleaa)